# How to assign values ​to all elements added in the collection editor at the same time with propertygrid in C#

Tags: c#, propertygrid

i have a custom struct.
eg.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace MotionSystem.BLL
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ValueTypeTypeConverter<SpeedParam>))]
    public struct SpeedParam
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double Speed { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Acc { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Dcc { get; set; }
        public SpeedParam(double speed, double acc, double dcc)
        {
            this.Speed = speed;
            this.Acc = acc;
            this.Dcc = dcc;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Speed：{Speed} Acc：{Acc} Dcc：{Dcc}";
        }
    }
    public class ValueTypeTypeConverter<T> : ExpandableObjectConverter where T : struct
    {
        public override bool GetCreateInstanceSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override object CreateInstance(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IDictionary propertyValues)
        {
            if (propertyValues == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyValues");

            T ret = default(T);
            object boxed = ret;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in propertyValues)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = ret.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Key.ToString());
                if (pi != null && pi.CanWrite)
                {
                    pi.SetValue(boxed, Convert.ChangeType(entry.Value, pi.PropertyType), null);
                }
            }
            return (T)boxed;
        }
    }
}
```

and a class with a property about this struct array

```
public class MyClass
{
   public SpeedParam[] SpeedParam { get; set; }
}
```

In the collection editor form, I use a "Add" button to add 3 SpeedParam elements, usually, i can use a propertygrid in collection editor form to assign the element one by one for example set SpeedParam[0] then set SpeedParam[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW3Kp.png) and then set SpeedParam[2], but now I would like to add a button in this collection edit form that when i click a button to assign all the elements.
I thought about it for a long time and there was no ending plan. Some one have a good idea?

Comment: Could you please state more clearly what you mean by "click a button to assign all the elements". Assign to what? Whats should this button be located?

Comment: i reedit it， you can see it again

Comment: What is "all the elements"? Always three? With which values?

Comment: not always three, it's dynamically add by user, there may be many. I just want give user a function that help user to assgin all elements convenience, not set the element one by one  it's very time consuming @Klaus Gütter

Comment: What about a TypeConverter for the `MyClass.SpeedParam` property converting between `SpeedParam[]`and `string`? Then the user can just type in something like "100 +2 -3;120 +3 -4" and it will be converted to two SpeedParam values.